# Intelij 15 edit non project files by default

Tags: intellij-idea

In InteliJ 14 when you opened a non project file using

`idea some-file.txt`

You were prompted a quick pop up asking whether you wanted to modify the file once you attempt to modify it which would default to 'Yes' so it was quick to just press enter.

However in InteliJ 15 
Same command
`idea some-file.txt`

Prompts a dialog
[image]

Which defaults to 'Cancel' is there a way to just set InteliJ to always edit non project files not just in current session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Non Project Files Unlocker](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7635?pr=idea)