# Edit non-project files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, open-source, projects-and-solutions

I've been trying to edit a non-project file using IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.3, and I cannot get around the write only protection.

I do not get a pop-up asking whether I would actually like to edit the non-proj file, as seen in this post: [Intelij 15 edit non project files by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768711/intelij-15-edit-non-project-files-by-default)

And I've also installed the `Non Project Files Unlocker` plugin, unfortunately it did not seem to have an impact (yes I restarted the IDE).

If anyone has had the same experience or if someone has a workaround/solution please let me know. All suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What file type do you edit? Where is it located? What are the file permissions? Are you sure it's not configured as a part of some project library?

Comment: Java file, not sure on the permissions as the path to the file is located in the maven repository and I could not get to it via command line. Yes it is configured as a part of another project's library.

Comment: Are you trying to edit a decompiled class file (or one with attached sources) inside a jar?

Comment: If this file is inside a jar or a decompiled class file, you can't edit it.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that this isn't actually possible. My solution was just to create a new project, and edit the code in that new intellij window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--> Create new IntelliJ project (for the 'non-project' file), edit the code, build that code using maven, open original intelliJ project, and the desired file is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but not with non-project files, rather with all the files, IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.3. Most of the time I wasn't able to edit anything. Played with file protection, checked/unchecked write permissions, nothing seemed to work.

What helped me eventually is to go to File->Preferences...->Plugins, then disabled the IdeaVim plugin.

I found that solution here:

https://superuser.com/questions/951374/cant-type-delete-in-intellij-idea-osx-el-capitan-4/952647#952647?s=38d8d09b1b824d14aa70da4954b5bf66

check the accepted answer.