# Open arbitrary file in existing Intellij Project

Tags: intellij-idea

*Intellij* is my goto editor for .. just about *everything* . I tried *sublime*, *vscode*, *adam* and others.. and I do always come back to IJ.

In the past I had been able to use the *command line launcher* `/usr/local/bin/idea` and it would open a general file *in the currently opened Intellij project*. Split second to open.   That is not working presently : instead a *new Intellij window/application* is launched for the sole purpose of editing maybe a small text file. This can take minutes and lots of memory.

The command line options to the *launcher* are v limited and do not include specifying "open in new window" or not:

```
$idea --help
Usage:
  /usr/local/bin/idea -h | -? | --help
  /usr/local/bin/idea [project_dir]
  /usr/local/bin/idea [-l|--line line] [project_dir|--temp-project] file[:line]
  /usr/local/bin/idea diff <left> <right>
  /usr/local/bin/idea merge <local> <remote> [base] <merged>
```

I would also mention: I do want separate windows for Intellij *projects* so do ***not*** want to reset this option under `Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Project Opening`:

[image]

Also: note there is a similar question here
[Edit non-project files in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379269/edit-non-project-files-in-intellij) but that question *does* require specific project-related capabilities and does not answer my question. My question is for opening general text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution is to use the `--temp-project` command line option. It creates an unnecessary additional window but does not open an entirely new Application. It's pretty quick. E.g. for

```
  idea --temp-project zoo.data
```

we get a project with that one file:

[image]

I'd still prefer to open the arbitrary file within the currently opened Project - which did happen in the past.